# Extract all Images from HTML whose width or height higher than a specified value - Regex

Tags: regex, asp-classic, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to make a small link share function with Classic ASP like LinkedIn or Facebook.

What I need to do is to get HTML of remote URL and extract all the images whose width are greater than 50px for example.

I can crawl and take the HTML and also I can find the images with this regex:

`<img([^<>+]*)>`

It matches; `<img src="/images/icon.jpg" width="60" height="90" style="display:none"/>`

Then I'm able to extract the path but sometimes it matches `<img src="/track.php" style="display:none" width="1" height="1"/>` which is not a real image.

Anyway, I feel like you are gonna be mad because of classic ASP but my company ....

I know there are lots of topics about this issue and mostly, they recommend not to USE regex but I couldn't find a way to this with classic asp. Is there a component or something to this?

Regards

Comment: You cannot compare numbers with a (sane) regex.

Comment: What happens if the image tag does not specify dimmensions?

Comment: @SLaks♦: Ok, then I guess I have to check every image the regex matches with Microsoft.XMLHTTP. [link](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/get-remote-image-width-and-height-using-pure-asp-113649.html)

Comment: Javascript would be the way to go for this. Are you able to use that?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close:

```
<img [^>]*width="(0?[1-9]\d{2,}|[5-9]\d)"[^>]*>
```

It accepts image tags with a width of 50 or greater.

Edit: tags with unspecified widths:

```
<img [^>]*width="(0?[1-9]\d{2,}|[5-9]\d)"[^>]*>|<img ((?!width=)[^>])*>
```

Comment: Crazy problems beget crazier solutions....   I agree with @SLaks, though.  If you have any other option, take it.

Comment: thanks @agent-j but as @Francisc stated, regex will fail if image tag does not specify dimensions.

Comment: What if height comes before width?

Comment: Another dead end for regex to parse HTML with Classic ASP :)

Comment: the `[^>]*` matches until the end of the image tag (or until something like `alt="Hello > world"`. So, it doesn't matter where the height attribute is.